# How to disable/leave docker swarm mode when starting docker daemon?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

is there any way to disable/leave the swarm mode of docker when starting the daemon manually, e.g. `dockerd --leave-swarm`, instead of starting the daemon and leave the swarm mode afterwards, e.g. using `docker swarm leave`?

Many thanks in advance,
Aljoscha

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is anticipated by docker developers. When node leaves swarm, it needs to notify swarm managers, that it will not be available anymore.

Leaving swarm is a one time action and passing this as an configuration option to the daemon is weird. You may try to suggest that on docker's github, but I don't think it will have much supporters.

Perhaps more intuitive option would be to have ability to start dockerd in a way that communication to docker swarm manager would be suspended - so your dockerd is running only locally, but if you start without that flag (--local?) it would reconnect to swarm that it was attached before.